# Data layer Organization

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I am stuck in my app development. I am trying to develop simple numismatic app. This app should be built this way:

Countries DataTable -> SubCountries DataTable (example: Germany -> BRD -> DDR->...) -> SelectedCountryCurrencyList DataTable -> SelectedCountryCurrency -> SelectedCurrencyInfo View (It will contain 'add to my collection' button)

There's also the problem, that sometimes some countries are do not have any subcountries.

I am about storing the list of countries, subcountries and currencynames in plist.
The full information about currency (including image) in SQL DB on remote server.

So, my question is **how should I build the structure of my plist for this given situation. Should I store all of the stuff in one single plist file, or should I create more files?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use sqlite (with fmdb wrapper) or coredata.  You could also pull down more of the currency information and images to the local store.  That would make the relational queries faster, full currency and images faster and provide the benefit of full functionality on an occasionally connected device.

Comment: Thank you for answer. This approach (SQLite) already came me in mind. A couple of hours studying SQLite. Core Data is not the best approach due relation problems. Ok, plist question is solved due lack of need.

Comment: There's only one more question. May I keep SQLite file somewhere on remote server and use it in my iPhone via internet?

Comment: Sure - in the end sqlite is just a file so you could download it via a get request.  You could even ship with a default database and when a new one is available, download it and switch over to it.